# Creating a discord bot and want to load the data from .json file in the specific .py file located at the cog folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am creating a python discord bot and stuck on loading data.
My folder structure is like this

```
|Bot folder
|-Cogs
|--ping.py
|-Data Storage
|--.env
|--channel.json
|-main.py
```

Below are the codes i am using for my files:-
main.py

```
#MODULES
import os
import asyncio
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands

#LOADING ENVIORMENT FILE
load_dotenv(dotenv_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Data Storage', '.env'))

#ACCESSING BOT TOKEN
Token = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')

#DEFINING INTENTS
intents = discord.Intents.all()

#BOT PREFIX
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)

#MAIN CODE

# (1) Loading Cog's.
async def load():
    cog_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Cogs')
    for filename in os.listdir(cog_dir):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            await bot.load_extension(f'Cogs.{filename[:-3]}')

# () Running the Bot.
async def main():
    await load()
    await bot.start(Token)

asyncio.run(main())
```

ping.py (want to modify this file)

```
#MODULES
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#DEFINING INTENTS
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = intents)

#MAIN CODE
class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('|---------------------------------------------------->')
        print(f' #{self.bot.user.name} has invaded the server...')
        print(f' Bot Id: {self.bot.user.id}')
        print('|---------------------------------------------------->')
        print('     ')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

channel.json

```
{
    "BOT_CHANNEL_ID": "1196004195292164136"
}
```

In ping.py I want to load the data from channel.json (BOT_CHANNEL_ID) so that I can send an embed message in that channel that the bot goes online and ready to use.

I tried to writing the code in ping.py like this but it is not working.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

class Ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is online!')

        # Load the channel ID from the JSON file
        channel_id = await self.load_channel_id()
        print(f'Loaded channel ID: {channel_id}')

        # Get the channel object
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(int(channel_id))
        print(f'Found channel: {channel}')

        if channel:
            # Send a message to the specified channel
            await channel.send('Bot is online!')

    async def load_channel_id(self):
        # Load the entire JSON file
        json_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Data Storage', 'channel.json')

        with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)

        # Fetch the desired channel ID
        return data.get("BOT_CHANNEL_ID", None)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Ping(bot))
```

Indeed the bot is going online but it not sending the message in the specified channel. Also it is not giving any error messages in the terminal. I tried using try: and except: but again it is not giving the error message either. So, I am pretty confused. Looking for the help on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` would return the file path to the folder `ping.py` is in, `Bot folder/Cogs`.

With `os.path.join`, the file path will be `Bot folder/Cogs/Data Storage/channel.json`, which isn't the file path that you're looking for; `Bot folder/Data Storage/channel.json`.

Therefore, `load_channel_id` would return None, and `if channel` would prevent any error from occurring.

All you have to do is remove `os.path.dirname(__file__)` since it's not the file path you want.

```py
json_file_path = os.path.join('Data Storage', 'channel.json')
```

Next time, to debug, you can try using `print` statements to check if, in this case, the file path is correct.